# AS3 memory management

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, memory, garbage-collection

I have a question about as3 memory management.

For example if i have class

```
public class CustomizationScreen extends MovieClip {
       private var a:Display;
       public var b:Buttons;
       public function CustomizationScreen() {
           a = new Display(200,-20);
           b = new Buttons(900,-100,"Next");
           addChild(a);
           addChild(b);
       }
}
```

And i instantiate that class in main class

```
public class Main extends MovieClip {
   public var c:CustomizationScreen;
   public function Main() {
       c = new CustomizationScreen(200,-20);
       c.b.addEventListener(Event,func);
       addChild(c);
   }
   // func
}
```

Will this be enough for c object to be garbage collected?

```
c.removeEventListener(Event,func);
removeChild(c);
c=null;
```

Or do i also need to remove a and b object from c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you should know, garbage collection is not an ontime process and dont be done untill a valuable mount of memory is allocated..

[The red line is our maximum allowed memory, then garbage called](https://cdn.tutsplus.com/active/uploads/legacy/tuts/139_QTgarbageCollection/image2.png)

but the most important thing about garbage ability of your object, is that there must not left any handler in your object which comunicates with other objects in out of your class. For example event listeners must be removed correctly.

Also take a look on this article
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-garbage-collection-in-as3--active-4412

And in answering your main question :
Yes. Your class will be successfully garbage collected!!

Answer (score 1):

You should define c in the class instead in the function

```
  public class Main extends MovieClip {

       private var c:CustomizationScreen;

       public function Main() {
            c = new CustomizationScreen(200,-20);
            c.b.addEventListener(Event,func);
            addChild(c);
       }

  }
```

and you need to remove eventListener on c.b, not on c.

```
public function dispose():void
{
     c.b.removeEventListener(Event,func);
     removeChild(c);
     c=null;
}
```

You'd better set a and b to null in CustomizationScreen, if there are reference to a and b from other class.

Comment: well this was quick example,and you are right about that i will edit it, c.removeEventListener and c.b.removeEventListener  will both work since parent class will search for event in child class.Why would i need to set a and b to null since the object that they are in is nulled?Can you give quick example of that when i would need to null a and b.  Thank you